# What is the simplest way to check if PHPSUEXEC or SUPHP is enabled, with a php script

Tags: php, suphp

I need to check if PHPSUEXEC or SUPHP is enabled. How can I do that within a php script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easyiest way to check if its enables is something like this

```
ob_start();
phpinfo();
$sTmp ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

$iPos = strripos($sTmp, "PHPSUEXEC"); //not sure how the string in phpinfo is spelled!!
if($iPos === false) {
 echo "not found";
} else {
 echo "found";
}
```

hope that helps!

Cheers,

Dennis